# Valid format for DateTime? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've tried the following input:

8/14/2013 5:00 am, 8/21/2013 12:00 pm, 8/31/2013 5:00 am and 8/31/2013 5:00:00 am

I keep getting errors that they are invalid for DateTime. I'm using Orchard CMS and don't wanna do extra parsing/validation.

Comment: they look valid to me

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("8/14/2013 5:00 am")` works fine (at least in en-us) - Can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your CMS is configured for dd/mm/yy format rather than mm/dd/yyy.
try 14/8/2013 5:00 am for instance

Comment: I think you're right. But it's weird coz there are other similar date fields which handle mm/dd/yyy correctly. Hmm...